# Java generics of having return type as Class<T> or Class<?>

Tags: java, class, generics, wildcard, return-type

I have the below method in Generics :

```
private <T extends BaseResponse, U extends RequestEnvelope, V extends BaseTransformer>
    ParentBox<T> getResponse
    (U payload, V transformer, String entityType, Class<T> responseType) {
        Box<String> box;
        try {
            box= transformAndSerialize(payload, transformer);
        } catch (TransformException e) {
            LOG.error("Failed", e);
            return new ParentBox<>(ParentBoxStatus.TRANSFORM_ERROR, null);
        } catch (SerializeException e) {
            LOG.error("Failed", e);
            return new ParentBox<>(ParentBoxStatus.SERIALIZE_ERROR, null);
        }
}
```

Need to change the above method in the below return type as Class or Class<?> format highlighted in bold :

```
private <T extends BaseResponse, U extends RequestEnvelope, V extends BaseTransformer>
    **Class<T>** getResponse
    (U payload, V transformer, String entityType, Class<T> responseType) {
        Box<String> box;
        try {
            box= transformAndSerialize(payload, transformer);
        } catch (TransformException e) {
            LOG.error("Failed", e);
            return new ParentBox<>(ParentBoxStatus.TRANSFORM_ERROR, null);
        } catch (SerializeException e) {
            LOG.error("Failed", e);
            return new ParentBox<>(ParentBoxStatus.SERIALIZE_ERROR, null);
        }
}
```

This is giving me a compile time error. How can I fix this

Comment: Your code returns a `Box` instance. What are you expecting it to return in order to fit to the signature of `Class<T>`?

Comment: I am bit new to generics and I want to return a class of any type. I can use object but I have to put If conditions to check instances

Comment: Did you mean something like `T getResponse( ...., Class<T> responseType)`?

Comment: yes which can have a return type of class<T> or class<?>

Comment: Well, you could have `Class<T> getResponse( ..., Class<T> responseType)` but in that case this wouldn't make sense as you'd return the same class you've passed as a parameter (you'd not return an _instance_ of that class). You could also use `Class<?>` would would lose the actual return type (you'd need to check again). Or do you mean something like `<R extends T> Class<R> getResponse(..., Class<T> rt)`?

Comment: Ya you are right you need to have a base class which can be of any type else it will make no sense as you would return the same class